# Git: first commit gets lost after the second commit

Tags: eclipse, git, git-commit

I only did some commits locally without pushing to the remote by using Eclipse.

And this happened:

After I did the second commit, my first commit disappeared and the files included in the first commit list appeared in the second commit list.

Is this a normal move for git commit?

Is this a consequence of some setting I accidentally made in git configuration?

Or how can I make two commits without being merged automatically because I want to put different comments to them.

Comment: What you are describing is that your second commit was an "amend" commit which squash with the previous commit. Di you check any "amend" option when committing in eclipse?

Comment: Thank you so much. It should be that which is bothering me all the time.